# Console prompts error : Compound class names not permitted

Tags: selenium2, java

The thing what I wanted to do was, write java code for automate the sending an email via gmail. When I try to locate element of send button it throws following errors.
The code I used, is like this;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("r7")).click();
```

Error

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"r7"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.11 seconds
```

I searched the reason for it. I found these using firebug.

```
<div id=":rx" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3 T-I-JW" tabindex="1" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" data-tooltip="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" aria-label="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" data-tooltip-delay="800">Send</div>
```

id is not static in every time of the send button. 
But class is same in every message window.

you can see it by looking at this (from firebug console) and previous one.

```
<div id=":r7" class="T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3 T-I-JW" tabindex="1" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" data-tooltip="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" aria-label="Send ‪(Ctrl-Enter)‬" data-tooltip-delay="800">Send</div>
```

Finally I tried this code,

```
driver.findElement(By.className("T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3 T-I-JW")).click();
```

It gives this error,

```
The given selector T-I J-J5-Ji aoO T-I-atl L3 T-I-JW is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted
```

How I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to search for the id ":rx" ?  (Your first example is missing the colon which is why I ask)

Comment: I tried it more, in every time it gives the same error, the id is dynamic. it changes. but class is same.

Comment: Are you using angularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the in the class name  that you have used `T-I J-J5-Ji ao0 T-I-atl T-I-JW` ,

```
T-I

J-J5-Ji

ao0

T-I-atl

T-I-JW
```

are all different classes. When you use the following

```
driver.findElement(By.className("T-I J-J5-Ji ao0 T-I-atl T-I-JW"));
```

the spaces between the class name confuses the method as to which class it should look for.

Try the following :

```
package testPkg;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Gmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.lk/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        String s= driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(s);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        String s1= driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(s1);

        WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Send')]"));
        driver.quit();


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Code tested on Ubuntu machine and working perfectly. The above code doesn't take into account adding the email address of the recipient and the message body.

Comment: I tried those 3 ways. it doesn't work brother, console says     "Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='T-I J-J5-Ji ao0 T-I-atl T-I-JW']"}"

Comment: did it say unable to locate element in all three cases?

Comment: I'll comment each errors here

Comment: First -  "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[class='T-I J-J5-Ji ao0 T-I-atl T-I-JW']"}" ,                  Second - "Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.ao0.T-I-atl.T-I-JW"}"

Comment: Can you try this 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'T-I-atl') and contains(@role,'button')]))

Comment: Also you can try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'J-J5-Ji') and contains(@tabindex,'1')]"));

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(""//div[text()='Send']")) should also work

Comment: These codes do not prompt any error on the console, but the send button is not functioning. did you try those?

Comment: did you use click method after these?

Comment: I tried it. I think It will be easy if we find xPath for this button. I also tried. can you try and send it to me. location is gmail send button.

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: Actually it worked..

Comment: button is worked. sometimes there is a delay before message sending function, so console shows a timeout error. at that instant, the button is not worked. there can be any other solution also for this..

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Send']")).click();       . this also worked for me.