# Error seen while automating the Gmail page. Pls help!

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While running the following code:

```
package prac.sample;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;


public class SelTestDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver test1 = new FirefoxDriver();
    test1.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    test1.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement email = test1.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    email.sendKeys("srinivaspavan@gmail.com");
    WebElement next = test1.findElement(By.id("next"));
    next.click();
    WebElement password = test1.findElement(By.ById.id("Passwd"));
    password.click();
    password.sendKeys("tftctctc141414");
    WebElement signin = test1.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
    signin.click();
}

}
```

I see the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:    
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Passwd"}
Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09  19:55:52'
```

Please help.

Comment: This works for me with Webdriver version  2.49 but one Q. Why do you need to do a password.click(); before typing the password?

Comment: Maybe do not post passwords in the code! :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened because Selenium script was not able to find the element in the time duration mentioned.

This happens when your page is not loaded inside the time frame that Selenium has set for locating elements.

The best approach to handle this is to use the `waits( )`. You can use either implicit or explicit wait- the latter is preferable.

eg- If you use implicit wait, then it will wait for the duration for each element. You can do something like this

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitylyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Other wise, you can use the explicit wait condition and then wait for desired element to be present or load and then carry on with your test. Something on the lines of-

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait();

Webelement ele = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
```

The `elementToBeClickable()` can be any one of the different conditions allowed by the expected conditions class.

Read this for a better understanding- [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/)

Comment: I tried the solution you mentioned, but I am still seeing the error.

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16424/console-prompts-error-compound-class-names-not-permitted/16427#16427 Refer to the ans given by me. I have added the code for automating Gmail

Comment: However, which wait did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You have written a wrong code for finding an password element

Your code is -

```
WebElement password = test1.findElement(By.ById.id("Passwd"));
password.click();
password.sendKeys("tftctctc141414");
```

And it should be as -

```
WebElement password = test1.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
password.click();
password.sendKeys("tftctctc141414");
```

Mistake - you are using `By.ById.id` method

Comment: This actually does not answer the question and won't solve the problem. `By.ById.id()` is actually running `By.id()` static method, because `By.ById` inner class extends `By` abstract class and thus inherits `id()` method. I agree, writing `By.ById.id()` makes things less readable but it is not a reason of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is mainly because script is not giving time to load page. You have to use `Thread.sleep(ms)`

I have solved your problem and giving solution below.

Solution :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;  
import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  

public class SelTestDemo
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    try
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver test1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        test1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        test1.get("http://www.gmail.com");
        test1.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement email = test1.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        email.sendKeys("srinivaspavan@gmail.com");
        WebElement next = test1.findElement(By.id("next"));
        next.click();
        WebElement password = test1.findElement(By.id("Passwd"));
        //password.click(); no need to click here
        Thread.sleep(3000); // or you can use thread.sleep and wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)); both
        password.sendKeys("12raopavan#");
        WebElement signin = test1.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
        signin.click();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 
}
```

Let me know this solved your problem.

Comment: Using thread.sleep is considered a bad practice. Instead the use of Explicit or Implicit wait is recommended.

Comment: I do not think so it is bad practice at all. I have seen many web project when I must use thread.sleep. As per standard it is last option to pause webdriver process.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/ Please read this.

Comment: I am not saying that Thread.sleep is very good option to choose. I am saying that If my script failed just because of less time given for loading page then I need to find a stable way. I have use mainly Explicit and implicit wait both. But in some scenario (like above) , script need to pause for sometimes. In such scenario only thread.sleep is worked. I have check with all possible wait here but only thread.sleep is solved my problem.

Comment: Then increase the waiting time. I have used up to 5000 seconds in my scripts for waiting. Using thread.sleep has many bad repercussions. Most of the waiting scenarios can be solved by waits.

Comment: Yes I have use only upto only 3000 ms. Not more than this.

Comment: Despite your defense I agree with log_file.  Avoid fixed waits

Comment: -1 for using explicit sleep. See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3764/what-are-some-examples-of-why-explicit-sleep-statements-are-bad to learn more.

Comment: @dzieciou Here question is not about using explicit wait. Here question is how can we make test case most robust. As per my understanding and knowledge, I have see many selenium test case example with Explicit wait. I am not saying it is good approach but it is also not bad approach when you used it in small quantity. This is hypertheoretical discussion. Down vote can not come for this type for answer.                             If you believe and can say with confidence that my approach is totally wrong then please give answer.

Comment: @Sagar007 I'm not saying that your solution will not solve the problem. However, it will introduce another one: you're introducing an artificial delay in test without explicitly stating what you're waiting for makes a test harder to understand and maintain. Read the links I and other people provided for more explanation. The fact that many tests are using `Thread.sleep()` does not mean it is a valid approach.

Comment: @dzieciou No doubt You are right in your approach. That is why I had make a comments if you have read. "// or you can use thread.sleep and wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));" Both approach can solve problems this is my solution. My solution does not contains only thread.sleep.